# Umbraco Non-Page Items

Tags: .net, content-management-system, umbraco

I've been working quite a bit with the Sitecore CMS, and I'm now trying to learn Umbraco.

What is the best method/practice for creating non-page items in Umbraco? In Sitecore, I would create items outside the web site's content tree, and access them via the API in my controller.

As a practical example, I'm trying to create a set of social media items that I can display as a menu in different parts of the site. In Sitecore, I would create a "Social Media" template with a name, icon and URL create several items from it within a specific folder. The controller would then loop through these items and create a menu wherever I needed it. Alternately, the content for a promo block could be stored in a separate item and included by any page.

What's the best way to achieve this result with Umbraco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umbraco can be setup in the same way.  I frequently create a "Settings" or "Data" folder in the content tree outside of the main website.  This allows for property pickers / data types that can select this "Non-page" data that is shared across the entire site.

You can certainly also simply directly access the items in this special area via the Umbraco API or by setting up a custom Examine Search index if there are lots of items.

Does that help?